# How to display public/private key pair PKCS11?

Tags: pkcs#11

How can I display a public/private key-pair generated via PKCS11 ? I use the CK_VALUE attribute template to display a Secret Key. That does not work for a key-pair. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like CK_VALUE is valid for Secret Keys and not a public/private key pair. What would be the way to display the value of those keys ?

Comment: See [my previous answer to similar older question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42508777/3325704).